# Azure WebSocket not working with Go httpPlatformHandler

Tags: azure, go, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I'm having a hard time making websocket works on an Azure Web App, I'm currently porting a Node app from Azure to a Go app.

WebSocket is enable on the portal and here's my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" processPath="d:\home\site\wwwroot\v-0.0.10.exe"
                      arguments=""
                      startupTimeLimit="60">
            <environmentVariables>
              <environmentVariable name="GOROOT" value="d:\home\site\wwwroot\go" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Of course locally it's working fine. At first I only tried this sample:

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func echoHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    io.Copy(ws, ws)
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/echo", websocket.Handler(echoHandler))
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getevn("HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT"), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.Error())
    }
}
```

On the client side I simply try to connect:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("url")
ws.onopen = function() { ws.send("test"); }
ws.onmessage = function(e) { console.log(e.data); }
```

When deployed on Azure, the readystate always stays at 0, onopen is never call. It ultimately failed saying there's an error connecting:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://***.azurewebsites.net/echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

I even tried with Gorilla Websocket example to see if the Go extended package was in cause.

Things I tried:

1. Removed the `<webSocket enabled="false" />` from web.config [same issue but it appears to take longer before occuring
2. Adding a standard `http.HandleFunc` to serve a "standard" page and it works fine.

I have a handful of Go app deploy to Azure, it's just the first one that I would need to use websocket, and I would like to know what I'm doing wrong / not understanding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This might be unrelated, but `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket` is now `golang.org/x/net/websocket`.

Comment: Yes, but until Jan 2016 this repo is still OK I think from what I understand, and in my code I changed it to the `golan.org/x/net/websoket` also after discovering that the code.google.com was going to be discontinued  It's just that I copy paste from Github for the SO question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reference your code and created a sample, it is working for me.
I didn`t do any custom web.config but using the default one come from Azure Deployment script.

here is the sample repo: https://github.com/shrimpy/gowebsockettry

[image]

Comment: Since when we are able to deploy go app to Azure via Git? I did not know that Kudu was able to handle Go app? This is a game changer for me now. Works as is when deploy via Git indeed, thank you for the eye opener, wow.

Comment: @DominicSt-Pierre we announce publicly last month https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/running-go-applications-on-azure-app-service/, feel free to submit us feedback via github https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu